# Products filter node js + sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using node js + sequelize. I want to filter result of products by selected options like vendor, price, delivery option and etc, but I can't understand how to make query exact.

now I am doing this, but this method works only when all filters are selected (AND operator). What should I do if user selects only 1 filter, or few of them ?

```
    let vendor = req.query.vendor;
    let priceFrom = req.query.priceFrom;
    let priceTo = req.query.priceTo;
    let delivery = req.query.delivery

            Product.findAll({
                where: {
                    vendor_id: {
                        in: vendor
                    },
                    price: {
                        $between: [priceFrom, priceTo]
                    },
                    {
                    delivery: delivery 
                    }
                }
            }).then(products => {
                res.render('product', {products: products});
                console.log(products)
            });
```

I see the only 1 way now to make this to write a lot of if-else statements for every occasion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, check for query params and make an object based on those query params, for example:

```
let vendor = req.query.vendor;
let priceFrom = req.query.priceFrom;
let priceTo = req.query.priceTo;
let delivery = req.query.delivery
let options = { where: {} };
if (vendor)
    options.where.vendor_id = {$in: vendor}
if (priceFrom && priceTo)
    options.where.price = {$between: [priceFrom, priceTo]}
if (delivery)
    options.where.delivery = delivery
Product.findAll(options)
  .then(products => {
      console.log(products)
      res.render('product', { products: products });
  });
```

Comment: With the latest version, this will not work. use [Op.between] and [Op.in] https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a package like [odata-sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata-sequelize). It simplifies the filter process.

```
var parseOData = require("odata-sequelize");
var sequelize = require("sequelize");
var query = parseOData(
  "$top=5&$skip=1&$select=Foo,Bar&$filter=Foo eq 'Test' or Bar eq 'Test'&$orderby=Foo desc",
  sequelize
);
```

this will produce

```
{
    attributes: ['Foo', 'Bar'],
    limit: 5,
    offset: 1,
    order: [
        ['Foo', 'DESC']
    ],
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            {
                Foo: {
                    [Op.eq]: "Test"
                }
            },
            {
                Bar: {
                    [Op.eq]: "Test"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, I have now added so examples codes